# Laravel testing: Unable to locate element

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I'm new to testing, and I am trying to create a test for a registered user, but I'm facing an error.

> Tests\Browser\AuthTest::a_user_can_register_correctly
> Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException: no such element:
> Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body
> first-name"}   (Session info: headless chrome=99.0.4844.83)

**Test code**

```
class AuthTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function a_user_can_register_correctly()
    { 
        $this->browse(function($browser){
            $browser->visit('/register')
                ->type('first-name', 'User')
                ->type('last-name', 'User')
                ->type('email', 'user@user.com')
                ->type('password', 'password')
                ->type('confirm_pwd', 'password')
                ->check('checkbox', 'agreement')
                ->click('button[type="submit"]')
                ->assertSee("You are register");
        });
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
        <input type="text" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['firstName'])) {
            echo $_POST['firstName'];
        } ?>" name="first-name" id="firstName" class="form-control"
               placeholder="First Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <input type="text" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['LastName'])) {
            echo $_POST['LastName'];
        } ?>" name="last-name" id="LastName" class="form-control"
               placeholder="Last Name">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-row my-4">
    <div class="col">
        <input type="email" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
            echo $_POST['email'];
        } ?>" required name="email" id="email" class="form-control"
               placeholder="Email*">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-row my-4">
    <div class="col">
        <input type="password" required name="password" id="password"
               class="form-control" placeholder="Password*">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-row my-4">
    <div class="col">
        <input type="password" required name="confirm_pwd"
               id="confirm-password" class="form-control"
               placeholder="Confirm Password*">
        <small id="error" class="text-danger"></small>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="agreement" class="form-check-input" required>
    <label for="agreement" class="form-check-label font-poppins text-white-50">
        I agree <a href="#">term, conditions, and policy </a>*
    </label>
</div>

<div class="submit-btn text-center my-5">
    <button type="submit" onclick="confirmPassword(event)"
            class="btn btn-dark rounded-pill text-white px-5"
            style="height: 50px;">Create account
    </button>
</div>
```

I have already searched for a problem and tried all of this:

- Update Chrome to the latest version
- Update the Chrome WebDriver
- One that got me multiple times: ensure the APP_URL variable in your .env file. Make sure this is the correct URL that the live application is running. IE, the parameter must match reality.
- Try without passing the CSS selector into the type method. According to the Dusk Docs, you don't have to do this - Dusk will attempt to find the field with the given name attribute. The CSS may be causing more issues than it's worth, but nothing helped.

Comment: Your input is named `first-name`, but has an id of `firstName`. Try to make those consistent.

Comment: @aynber I change that too, but still the same error